# Django loosely coupling database and views

Tags: database, django

Maybe this is a silly question, but I am new to large scale development in django. Basic django examples always show simple queries where you get a queryset and return the result set back to the template for use (e.g. a list of users). I was wondering is this really a best practice for a large site? Coming from the object oriented world, we have kept separate structures to loosely couple the database from business logic and views. One set of models would map directly to the tables in the database and use an ORM such as SqlAlchemy to automatically manage them but separate business models would be used to returned to the views for template usage based on business logic needs. They may have extra or fewer fields than the database table object depending on what information is needed for that template and come from a reusable code layer that contains the business logic. For example, sometimes you want to flatten a few columns from multiple database models in to one class that is easily consumable.

Also for situations such as transactions and connection handling, the reusable layer allows us to keep all knowledge of the database out of the views. The middle layer explicitly creates and uses a session to be used on different objects as needed and closes the session when done though I rarely see evidence of this done in django. While it is more development work, it tends to give better performance results. Is this separation of models and business logic all this considered overkill in the django world? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what you explain I get the sensation that you would like to build a middleware layer that caches queryset results in a reusable format.

Django takes the opposite approach: [querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy). They do not touch the database until their result is needed in a view. When combining queries, it is only the combined query that hits the database.

Apart from that, [caching and querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets) gives good performance for most situations if you construct your models sensibly.

Comment: It's not really from the caching perspective but from the encapsulation of business logic and managing transactions perspectives. In the case of an ordering system for example, I would want to allow multiple kinds of forms (guest check out form, logged in check out form, mobile app service call, etc) to ultimately lead to the creation of an order object in the database with one set of business logic. For retrieving information, I may have different view methods (templates/rest) serving up the same queries to retrieve several objects. Was just curious what are some ways others handle this.